# Issue with the karate parallel runner

Tags: karate

I wanted to see if anyone else might have observed the same issue. I looked in the project for any open/closed issues that might be like this but did not notice any.

I noticed that when I use the Karate Parallel runner (which we have been using for a while now), that every GET, POST, DELETE request gets called 2x, observed in the karate logs which came in the console.

When I do not use the Karate Parallel runner only a single request is made.

I noticed this when performing a POST to create a data source in our application. When I went to the applications UI to verify the new data source was created, I saw 2 of them. This leads me down the path to research further what might be happening.

```
Using Karate v0.9.5 with Junit 5
```

> **minimalistic Example -**
>
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UWnNtxGO7gr-_Z80MLJbFkaAmuaVGlAD/view?usp=sharing

**Steps To Run The Code  -**

```
Extract ZIP
cd GenericModel    
mvn clean test -Dtest=UsersRunner
Check the console logs API scenario get executed 2X
```

**Note - It works fine for me for karate V0.9.4 with Junit 5**

Comment: no command-line instructions, extra folders present, not followed the instructions properly: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas Sorry for the trouble, have updated clean example link and Steps to run the code please check.

Comment: See my answer. I suggest you take a week off and read the documentation end-to-end. It will be worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up parallel runner and JUnit runner and ended up having both in one test method. Please read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-5-parallel-execution

Note that you use the normal `@Test` annotation not the `@Karate.Test` one.